# identify input is from particular list within a nested list

Tags: java, list

```
List<List<String>> listOflists = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> firstList = new List<String>();
firstList.add("NameX");
firstList.add("AgeX");
firstList.add("DesignationX");
listOflists.add(firstList);

List<String> secondList = new List<String>();
secondList.add("NameY");
secondList.add("AgeY");
secondList.add("DesignationY");
listOflists.add(secondList);

List<String> thirdList = new List<String>();
thirdList.add("NameZ"); 
thirdList.add("AgeZ");
thirdList.add("DesignationZ");
listOflists.add(thirdList);
```

## Input:

My requirement is like "If i give Name? or Age? or Designation?" as input. I need to know that this particular input is from that list.

Example:
If i give "NameZ" as input, I need some clue that the input is from the thirdList.

Comment: Just iterate over your lists and check the strings until you've found `NameZ`, or do you have a more specific question than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java collections have a method called, `contains(item)` which will search the collection for the specified item.

In this case the best thing to do is just go over these lists and use this method.

```
String searchStr = "age";
for (List<String> list : listOflists){
    if (list.contains(searchStr)){
        // inside this list, do something
    }
}
```

If you are just looking for if an item is inside of collections, the fastest is by using a `Set` rather than a `List`, and would be more appropriate here.

Comment: You could get clever and subclass your list and re-implement **contains()**, but I don't think there would be any performance improvement, and frankly, "get clever" is often a synonym for "obfuscate".